# How to Get class/caption/handle of all windows elements in java

Tags: java, class, spy++

I am trying to create an app similar to spy++ in java, in which I can get class/caption/handle of every element which I am taking mouse over.
e.g. :

1. If we move mouse on task bar, the spy tool shows the info as : Handle : 000100AA Caption : Running applications Class : MSTaskListWClass
2. If we take mouse on one of the button of windows calculator(lets say "1") spy tool will show caption : 1

I m already getting foreground window with following code:

```
GetWindowTextW(GetForegroundWindow(), buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
```

and process name :

```
Pointer process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
                | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
        GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer1, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
```

But i am still not able to get captions and classes for buttons/textboxes. Please help to do the same.

Comment: Java is a very, very poor choice for this, because you need native code extensively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
We like it better if you show what (code) you have tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
 for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is for mouse click event.

Use [jnativehook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) to handle a global mouse click event. When the user clicks, find out the foreground window and its position.

You have to create a dll which will have the native winapi calls. Then load this dll in your java program.

1. First get the global mouse position with jnativehook's [nativeMousePressed](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/wiki/examples).
2. Find the handle for the [foreground window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .
3. Get the [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & [process id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) from the handle.

Comment: i m already getting the name foreground window and processId. But want to retrive the caption of each button/textbox or any element present on the active window on mouseover.If we move mouse on task bar, the spy tool shows the info as :                          Handle : 000100AA                                              Caption : Running applications                                                                Class : MSTaskListWClass